# How to dynamically add more Kafka topics to Logstash configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

Is there any option how to add to logstash kafka input multiple kafka topics? I am finding dynamic solution cause number of my topics are changing.

my logstash config looks like :

```
input {
    kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics => ["company0","company1","company2","company3","company4"]
    }
} 
output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "indextry"
      workers => 1
    }
}
```

in this solution I am using 5 kafka topics but in another case I want to use 20 for example.

Is there any dynamic solution how to add kafka topics here?

Comment: Does the solution have to be with logstash? If you use Kafka Connect you can use regex etc to specify multiple source topics

Comment: No it doesn't.. but currently I am working on Windows I tried to make some Kafka Connect elastic sink but without success.

Comment: Feel free to post another question with the issues you're having with Kafka Connect and I can answer it

Comment: Is it possible to run it on windows and make a pipeline which also can encode  JSON messages to AVRO  and send to elastic and in elastic decode it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logstash [kafka input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-topics_pattern) supports the use of a `topics_pattern` configuration.

```
kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics_pattern => ["company.*"]
}
```

This config will consume every topic that starts with "company".